# How long should diskutil resetUserPermissions take (Catalina)?

Tags: terminal, permission, catalina, diskutil

I am following [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538) because of [this issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250772644?page=1).
The Terminal has been going on for about 2.5hrs and I do not know of a way to see a progress bar or know if it is stuck or if something else is happening.

What can I do? 
My SSD Home folder is about 280GB big so I understand it may take a while but, how long? 
I am on a 2016 MacBook Pro (15") with macOS 10.15.1.

Answer (score 1):

2.5 hours. No way. It’s stuck, or lost.
Open activity monitor in utilities and look for the running process. Put `resetUserPermissions` in the search bar.
Or in The activity monitor, if you find it, stop the process.

Comment: Done! Then? How much should I wait before I consider it lost? Is it bad if it does so? What should I do instead?

Comment: Why would it fail to complete?

Comment: A standard system SD should be done in a few minutes at most.

Comment: then what is happening? I followed the steps in the support article...

Answer (score 0):

You asked: "How long should diskutil resetUserPermissions take (Catalina)?"

If you follow the steps in your linked Apple support article under the heading, "If Terminal says that permissions reset failed", resetUserPermissions should finish in less than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Following the steps in the Apple Support article, the terminal command "diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`" never stops (within 8 hours).

My symptom that led me to try to correct permissions is that every few days, most files in my home directory fail to open using Apple apps and others (Excel, BBEdit, etc.). Oddly, pdfs that fail to open with Preview DO open with Adobe Acrobat Reader.

A restart seems to correct the issue for a day or two. Then I'm back to "the file  couldn't be opened."